# why does "source ~/.profile" keep adding to my $PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, path

*This is not a problem affecting me in any way, but just for curiosity...*

I have added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin`
 to my *~/.profile* to include a new directory into my bash search.

Then, I ran `$ source ~/.profile` to reload may shell and I checked my path using `$ echo $PATH`

**The question is:**
- why every time I ran `source ~/.profile`, it appends the same information again,
- how can I clear it?

**What I have tried:**
- Tried running it multiple times and it keeps adding the same
- Tried to figure out what does the `source` command does but could not find where it is `which source`

Comment: Don't source `~/.profile` more than once per shell session. Duplicate entries in `PATH` don't really hurt anything, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question:

> why every time I ran source ~/.profile, it appends the same
>   information again

Simply, `source <FILE>` does not *reload* your shell.  It only
executes all commands saved in `<FILE>` as if they were typed directly
by you in the terminal.

Second question:

> how can I clear it?

To reload shell open a new terminal
window/tab.  Doing just `bash` or `exec bash` won't work because a new
process will inherit its parent environment.

Third question:

> Tried to figure out what does the source command does but could not
>   find where it is which source

As I explained once here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202326/72304:

> All commands that can be run in Bash without typing an explicit path
>   to it such as ./command can be divided into two parts: Bash shell
>   builtins and external commands. Bash shell builtins come installed
>   with Bash and are part of it while external commands are not part of
>   Bash. This is important because Bash shell builtins are documented
>   inside man bash and their documentation can be also invoked with help
>   command while external commands are usually documented in their own
>   manpages or take some king of -h, --help flag. To check whether a
>   command is a Bash shell builtin or an external command:
>
> ```
> $  type local 
>  local is a shell builtin
> ```
>
> It will display how command would be interpreted if used as a command
>   name (from help type). Here we can see that local is a shell builtin.
>   Let's see another example:
>
> ```
> $ type vim 
> vim is /usr/bin/vim
> ```

In your case:

```
$ type source
source is a shell builtin
```

Now we know it's not an external command but a shell bultin (this is why `which` does not find it) so we need to use `help` to see what it does:

```
$ help source 
    source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
    entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
    If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
    when FILENAME is executed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
    FILENAME cannot be read.
```

Answer (score -1):

`source` executes the content of the file passed as argument in the current shell.

It appends the same information again because `export` is appending a string to `PATH`, without checking anything (it is not checking if the substring that you want to append is already in the variable).

To avoid appending to PATH every time, you should save the values of your PATH without referring to itself, e.g.:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Edit: 
To check if the directory is already in PATH:

```
if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin:"* ]]; then
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
fi
```

Comment: wouldn't this overwrite any previous assignments to $PATH before this export?

Comment: Of course it does, if you want to use current PATH see my updated answer.